# Would obfuscating an android app affect performance

Tags: android

I have just finish building an android app. I want to obfuscate to secure the code. But I am scared cos some research dat I have done says obsfuscation affect appplication performance. I intend using Proguard. Please would obfuscating my android app with proguard affect it performance in anyway.

Comment: Why not try it to see for yourself? It shouldn't take long to compile an obfuscated version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using proguard, speed should not be affected.

Other methods may affect performance if the code to mask or obfuscate data is intensive, but it's likely to be minimal.